# Running nginx in a container as reverse proxy with dynamic configuration

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, google-cloud-platform, containers

I'm trying to setup nginx as a reverse proxy in a container for my containers (Docker Swarm) and static sites which are being hosted on Google Cloud Platform & Netlify

I'm actually able to run nginx in containers, but I'm really worried about the configurations.

1. How will I update my site configurations in nginx to all containers (add / remove location)?
2. Is attaching a disk is the best option to store logs?
3. Is there any fault in my architecture?

[image: Architecture]

If image isn't working, please use this link - https://s1.postimg.org/1tv4hka3zz/profitto-architecture_1.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hej Sanjay.

**Have a look at:**

https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy

https://traefik.io/

The first one is a modified Nginx Reverse Proxy by J.Wilder.
The Second one is a new and native Reverse Proxy created specially for such use cases.

Both are able to listen to the docker.socks and dnynamicly add new containers to the reverse-proxy backend.

Regarding your Architecture:
Why not running the Reverse-Proxy Containers inside the Swarm Cluster?

Related to logging, have a Look at the Docker Log-Drivers.
You can collect the Logs of all Containers with eg. fluentd or splunk.

Comment: I experimented a little with traffic, it does look promising. The reason for running nginx in a seperate cluster is because I'm running few CPU intensive tasks

Comment: You can build one big swarm cluster, then make the nodes who should hold the proxy (traefik or nginx) a master-node, and the other nodes who should hold the work-intensive load a "normal" swarm-worker. Then you can bind the proxy-service to manager nodes only!
Just an quick idea!
> Why that all? If thats all within one swarm cluster you can easly listen on docker swarm events (req. for proxy to discover new tasks)